# html button inside ng-repeat is not working

Tags: html, angularjs, onclick

I'm trying to import a list of customers, and I want to proceed to a personalized customer page with specific information about a customer (using function showit). I currently have this:

```
<table ng-controller="patientsCtrl" class="table-responsive" class="fixed">                     
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Policy Nr</th>
            <th>Pol. Type</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in patients | orderBy:'patID'">
            <td>{{ p.patID }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.policy_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.policy_type }}</td>
            <td> <button ng-click="showit(p.name)">check</button> </td>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is `showit` a function declared on the scope?

Comment: the function name in your controller should be $scope.showit = function(name){...}, if you use $scope of course.

Comment: showit is a function declared on a js file.
But i've also tried easier things like changing a variable value, and it doesn't work. I've this other button, 

<button ng-click="showit(p.name)">check</button>

that works outside the table, and doesnt work inside

Comment: @MariaP. If it's in a js file and not on $scope, then you would want to use onclick="showit(p.name)". When you use ng-click, you must have the function defined on the controller's scope

Comment: I'm new in all this, so perhaps I'm not explaining myself very well. Just pretend that it's written 
    <button ng-click="vari=true">check</button>    . the button is not working when inside the table (the function phase I will implement later)

Comment: @MariaP. post your controller code please

Comment: $scope.showit = function (name) { $scope.givename = name; }

Comment: working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/yuwqm6qr/1/

Answer (score 1):

> Just pretend that it's written `<button ng-click="vari=true">check</button>` . the button is not working when inside the table (the function phase I will implement later)

You have a scoping issue. The button is working inside the table but the data is not getting outside the table because of the scope hierarchy.

```
<div ng-controller="patientsCtrl">
    <p>{{vari}}</p>
    <table class="table-responsive" class="fixed">                     
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Policy Nr</th>
            <th>Pol. Type</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in patients | orderBy:'patID'">
            <td>{{ p.patID }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.policy_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.policy_type }}</td>
            <td> <button ng-click="$parent.vari=true">check</button> </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>{{vari}}</p>
</div>
```

`ng-repeat` creates a scope for each item in a collection. To put data on the controller's scope, use `$parent`.

From the Docs:

> The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index` is set to the item index or key.

-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat