# Call a function defined in parent scope inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

**Original question: (please skip to the EDIT)**

I am trying to make images of books which I am receiving clickable.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCrtl"> 
    <ul ng-repeat="x in browseBooks">
        <div id="{{x.bookId}}">
            <li>        
            <a href="" ng-click=logout()><img style="max-width:100px;" ng-src="{{x.img}}"></a>
                <p>{{x.name}}</p>
                <p>{{x.price}}</p>
                <br>
            </li>   
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Following the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939385/href-overrides-ng-click-in-angular-js) doesn't work, and the link to the angularjs site is broken.

I know the function logout works perfectly, as with button it is executing.
The problem with `<a>` tag I am unable to make the image trigger a desired function.

---

**EDIT**

I understand what my problem is, ng-repeat creates a child scope for each item in the loop. So trying to access the `logout()` method defined in parent scope is not working. ?

Any idea? even replacing `"logout()"` with `$parent.logout()` isn't working...

**EDIT2**

It is working, however all changes are local to inner scope...

Comment: At first glance... isn't it that the lack of `"` around  `logout()` in `ng-click` attribute breaks your anchor making it unclickable?

Comment: What @MattfromVisionApp said.

Comment: Even when I add the `""` around `logout()` it doesn't work.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working. Use: `<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="return theFunction();">Item</a>` unless you have some custom javascript logic to process `ng-click` attributes.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476550/html-button-inside-ng-repeat-is-not-working) question which is interesting

Comment: @MattfromVisionApp any idea how to make the scope of what is created inside ng-repeat see my logout function?

Comment: In your last edit you used `$parent` which looks like PHP, where you should use java, so drop the `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around `logout()`

and then you could use `javascript:void(0)` if needed and `#` doesn't work for you

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()"><img style="max-width:100px;" ng-src="{{x.img}}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   <li ng-click="logout()">        
    <a href="#"><img style="max-width:100px;" ng-src="{{x.img}}"></a>
        <p>{{x.name}}</p>
        <p>{{x.price}}</p>
        <br>
    </li>
```